# Character- and word-level convolutional neural network implementation

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, nlp, conv-neural-network

To process text, I'm trying to use character- and word-level CNN's to classify messy sentences. Conceptually, it seems this would help with mis-/nontraditional spellings, typos, and truncated words.

I'm confused how to manipulate the data to be fed in and processed correctly.

I'd like to iterate over the sentences in the text, using the character-level CNN to map the words of that sentence to corresponding vectors, and concatenating those vectors to the word-embedding output vectors for those words. The resultant tensor can be used again in another CNN for classification.

But the text is being fed in as a tensor of strings, with each element being a sentence, so iterating as if the text is a list of sentences won't work.

Example pseudocode of what I'm trying to do:

```
self.X_word_input = tf.placeholder(
    tf.int32, 
    [None, self.max_sentence_length], 
    name='x_word_input'
)

self.X_char_input = tf.placeholder(
    tf.string,
    [None, self.max_char_length],
    name='x_char_input'
)

logits = inference(self.X_word_input,
    self.X_char_input,
    self.max_sentence_length,
    self.max_word_length,
    self.num_classes,
    self.word_vocab_size,
    self.char_vocab_size,
    self.word_embedding_dim,
    self.char_embedding_dim,
    self.word_filter_sizes,
    self.num_word_filters,
    self.char_filter_sizes,
    self.num_char_filters
)

def inference(...):
    for sentence in x_char_input:
        words = sentence.split(' ')
        words_tensor = tf.constant(words)
        char_embedding = get_embedding(words_tensor)
        char_conv = get_convolutions(char_embedding)
        char_logits = get_logits(char_conv)
        words_map.append(char_logits)
    word_embedding = get_embedding(x_word_input)
    combined_embedding = tf.append([word_embedding, words_map], 1)
    combined_conv = get_convolutions(combined_embedding)
    predictions = get_logits(combined_conv)
```

Even if I can iterate to extract the sentences as strings, I need to turn each word, in each sentence, into its own tensor of characters so that the character-level CNN can produce the output vector for each word from its character-tensors.

How do I feed in the sentences, break them up, and iteratively generate the word mappings from the character CNN? Thanks!